# What exactly does this do: exec > > (command)

Tags: bash

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable/6052267#6052267) and [here too](https://superuser.com/questions/86915/force-bash-script-to-use-tee-without-piping-from-the-command-line/86955#86955) the following construction:

```
exec > >(tee -a script.log)
```

I know what the tee command is, and the (command...) usually means execute the `command` in a subshell, and exec replaces the current shell with a program, like `exec ls`, (but here there is no command) and additionally what is meant with the `> >`?

Can anybody clarify this dark wizzardy?

```
exec >{space}> (command)
```

@Seth? :) Any pointer where i can read more about this magic would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It replaces the current `bash` session with another, and writes the output of all commands to `script.log`.

In that way, you can use your `bash` shell normally, and you wouldn't see any difference (mostly), but all output is going to show up on your screen **and** in the `script.log` file.

From [exec manpages](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html):

> If command is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process. If no command is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment.

The `>(tee -a script.log)` magic creates a pipe, so instead of writing to a file like we would (with `>> script.log` in this case), we write to the process `tee -a script.log`, which does the same. For some reason unbeknown to me, using `>>` does not work, but writing to the named pipe works. [Source here](http://www.linuxtutorialblog.com/post/tutorial-the-best-tips-tricks-for-bash)

Comment: So, with other words i can have more redirections? Like exec >(somecomamnd) >(anothercommand) >(thirdone) > [empty mean STDOUT?] ? (and as i told, i know tee :)

Comment: you can also read from multiple things, for example `diff <(ls /one) <(ls /two)`

Comment: This is really very cool. Can make several pipe-like flows. Extremely powerful addition to cmd >somewhere 2>error and so on. I'm happy to learn new things. ;)