# How to get output from bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash - automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable)

For example

In Bash shell

```
user:/ & echo "Hello"
Hello
user:/ & date
Sat Mar 17 01:48:45 ICT 2012
```

How to get the "`Hello`" or "`Sat Mar 17 01:48:45 ICT 2012`" variables

I mean every output from command bash shell

The purpose of this point, I want to get those variables and do something with its.

Like, when echo Hello I want to reverse string to olleH and then print it out.

Something like this

```
echo "Hello"
olleH
```

---

More Information

In Command Line Interface ***Not in Shell Script

When I type a command echo,date (or whatever command) in the Command Line Interface, The output will show in the next line.

```
user:/ & echo "Hello" <br>
Hello
```

The "Hello" variable is the output of bash shell. So, I want to store output Hello into variable and pass into "Dictionary Script"

The Hello will matched and translated depend on Dictionary Script

```
Hello = Hi (Just example)
```

Now Hello translated into Hi, send back to shell and print out

Result

```
user:/ & echo "Hello" <br>
Hi
```

How can I grab the output?

Could I expose the Bash Shell source, edit and re-compile?

Could I grab from the `/proc/`BASHPID?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6052267/1258041)

Answer (score 1):

#### Attempt at answering edited question

From your edit, it sounds as if you want to have `bash` executing commands, but the outputs from bash should be passed to a 'transmogrifier' which changes the output according to your whims.

This is not going to be trivial; I'm not sure it will be usable for more than a few seconds of fun.

At one level, you want an interactive shell with its standard output (and maybe standard error) going to your modifier program:

```
bash -i 2>&1 | transmogrifier
```

For basic command line work, this will just about be usable, though line editing (even with just backspace) becomes a little problematic.  Command line editing becomes intolerable if `transmogrifier` is changing what you appear to be typing as you type it.  (I tried `bash -i 2>&1 | tee`, which worked surprisingly well, but `tee` just copies its input to its output; and I'm not sure why I chose `tee` instead of `cat`. An interrupt, though, killed the pipeline; just another thing you'd have to worry about.)

#### Attempt at answering unedited question

For the `Hello`, you would be best off using:

```
var1="Hello"
```

You could also use:

```
var1=$(echo "Hello")
```

For the date, you more or less must use the latter notation:

```
var2=$(date)
```

You can now do things with those variables, such as:

```
$ echo "$var1" | rev
olleH
$
```

Note that simple prompts such as '`$`' (for Bash and relatives) or '`%`' (for C shell and relatives) or '`#`' (for root) are conventional.

---

I had decided not to mention the use of backticks, but since [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) commented about them, they do, indeed, exist, and you may come across them in older scripts, and you should not write them in your own scripts.

The `$(...)` notation for command substitution, as it is called, is simpler in nested scenarios, such as:

```
cd $(dirname $(dirname $(which gcc)))/lib
```

compared with the backtick notation for the same operation:

```
cd `dirname \'dirname \\\`which gcc\\\`\``/lib
```

(Don't even think of trying to get that second line into MarkDown for comments!  That's why I've added this to the answer.)

Comment: I believe the poster wants to prank someone and doesn't want the have them explicitly assign their output to variables. Have a look at the last snippet: `echo "Hello"` -> `olleH`

Comment: It is probably also worth noting that in bash, backtics (e.g. `\`command\``) have the same effect as `$(command)` just in case you ever see that in a script somewhere (although I think most people consider backtics to be less readible)...

Comment: The question is at least ambiguous, @LevLevitsky, or possibly confused about command output and variables.  I answered one way that seemed to make some sense of the ambiguity, though the last request (for `olleH` to appear) could also be dealt with via `rev <<< Hello`, amongst other techniques.

Comment: It my fault to explain the question not clear

That I show is just the example so, Let's me explain again
In my first post