# how to reference a specific line from previous output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

On bash, I have the following (typical) scenario:

```
~/some/dir$ find | grep java
```

which outputs, for example

```
./subdir1/subdir2/file1.java
./subdir1/subdir3/file2.java
./subdir1/subdir4/file3.java
./subdir1/subdir2/file4.java
./subdir1/subdir6/file5.java
```

now I know that `file5.java`, which is the file I was looking for (for example), is on that subdir, so I execute:

```
vi subdir1/subdir6/file5.java
```

but in order to do this I have to either type the path (I know that using the TAB key speeds it up) or copy and paste the path to the file

the question is: is there a shortcut/variable on bash (or any other shell) that references the lines outputted by the previous command, so that I can say

```
vi [whatever the previous command returned on the 5th line]
```

, and that would be a nice time saver

thanks!

Comment: would vi $( find | grep java | head -5 | tail -1 ) be too complicated?

Comment: the problem is that I can't know before I execute the find on which line is the file that I want to edit, so it has to be on two different commands

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BASH history you can come close to `[whatever the previous command returned on line 5]`

Here is an example

```
 $ find -name "*.java"
 src/file1.java
 ...
 src/file5.java
 ...
 $ vi $( !! | head -5 | tail -1 )
```

In this example `!!` represents `[whatever the previous command returned]` in the sence that the command is executed again.

The following command
`| head -5 | tail -1` is a rather awkward way to say `[take line 5]` from the input

If you are after a particular filename you could as well specify that in the search expression as

```
$ vi $( !find | grep file5 )
```

If `find` takes a long time to execute you could save the output of `find` into a file and use that file instead.

```
$ find -name "*.java" | tee filelist.save
 src/file1.java
 ...
 src/file5.java
 ...
 $ vi $( grep file5 filelist.save )
```

Comment: I was hoping for a magic shorcut such as `vi €5`, but this one is fine! I'll use it with !! instead of !find (to re-execute the last command) and maybe write a little script to reduce keystrokes

Comment: `!!` will repeat whatever the last command was, if you're interested in making this slightly more general.

Answer (score 1):

add -n 5 in your grep command will do just that.

~/some/dir$ find | grep -n 5 java

Comment: the problem is that I can't know before I execute the find on which line is the file that I want to edit, so it has to be on two different commands

Comment: ah, but someone already answered that, you can use a subshell such as vi $(find | grep -n 5 java).

Answer (score 0):

This tool is exactly what I needed:

http://facebook.github.io/PathPicker/