# Reference stdout (i.e. output of previous command) quickly in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, readline

Is there a way to quickly (e.g. via a keyboard shortcut, etc.) to reference the output of the previous command's output that it wrote to stdout?

For example, if I did this:

```
which rails
```

and it returned `/usr/local/bin/rails` and then I wanted to open that file in textmate, I could re-type the output like this:

```
mate /usr/local/bin/rails
```

but is there a way to quickly reference the output without having to re-type it?

NOTE: I am aware I can just do `mate $(which rails)`, but I am specifically looking to reference stdout.

Comment: No, it's gone as far as Bash is concerned. It may be available in your terminal's scroll-back buffer (`screen` for example).

Comment: !! only has the input, not the output, the output is not stored anywhere except in the terminal buffer.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash - automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 4):

I use backticks with history reference:

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
$ mate `!!`
```

Actually, my editor (a script starting gvim) is aliased to `e`, so it looks even shorter:

```
$ e `!!`
```

and you can always bind to a hotkey (see bash man page for `bind` command and `readline support`).

Also, if you can use cut buffers (select with a mouse in an X application), a hotkey for something like the below might be useful:

```
$ e $(xclip -out)
```

The command will start the editor as above with whatever was in the cut buffer on command line. Given that many paths are selectable with just a double click, a selected path can be edited very quickly.

Comment: the \`!!\` way doesn't reference stdout; instead, it reruns the command. you cant test this by making "echo $RANDOM" and then "echo \`!!\`": the values will be different.

Comment: Which is enough for most practical purposes. Wasn't suggesting that all commands can be repeated keeping original effects, but many commands can be. And there is still truck to paste the selection...

Answer (score -1):

You could always run the command in backticks:

```
mate `which rails`
```

I have to say though that it feels a little, uh, risky.  What if your PATH has been tampered with so that which returns a different version of rails than what you really needed?  What if which returns nothing?  So, take care to close down all those error cases, or avoid them in some way (say, reading the path to rails from a config file, and writing a tool that builds that config file for you).