# How to print the previous linux command's output?

Tags: linux, shell, history

The problem is:

After user enter a linux command.

How can I get the output of the first command using another command?

Note: we cannot redirect output of first command to somewhere.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Are you looking for `output=$(command)` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash - automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable)

Comment: You seem to be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6052267/2235132) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)

```
$ date -d "12:00"
Thu Sep 19 12:00:00 EDT 2013
$ d=$(!!)
$ echo $d
Thu Sep 19 12:00:00 EDT 2013
```