# Append | tee ~/.output to every bash command

Tags: bash

How can I append `| tee ~/.output` to every single bash command?

I want to output the results of the last command so I can use them in a $variable.

Comment: See [bash - automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable)

Comment: `I want to output the results of the last command so I can use them in a $variable.` -- The accepted answer in the above question does this exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I you want to append a string to every bash command you can do it by rebinding your `enter` key to add the command string. Or if you prefer create a *secondary enter key* and use it.

You should do something like this:

```
bind 'RETURN: "  | tee ~/.output \n"'
```

In this way, everytime you press `enter` the `| tee ~/.output` get appended.

This is a `bash` only solution.