# Linux / CentOS - Need to monitor a specific process

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, monitoring

Please help.
So, I'm given a task to monitor a particular process in CentOS.

There are certain requirements.

1. Can't monitor using **PID**, because once process is killed or dead, solution is of no use.
2. It'll be great if I could know how much is the consumption of each thread of a process.

I've researched enough but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain what exactly you are trying to achieve, but this is how I would proceed:

## Suggested Approaches

### Multiple Process IDs per process name

`top -H -p $(pgrep <process_name> | paste -s -d, -)`

### Single Process ID per process name

`top -H -p $(pgrep <process_name>)`

## Further reading

- [Reuse command output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283097/reusing-output-from-last-command-in-bash)
- [Thread Monitoring with top](https://www.xmodulo.com/view-threads-process-linux.html)
- [Turn stdout into comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714355/turning-multi-line-string-into-single-comma-separated)

## Suggestion

Maybe think about implementing a solution like Prometheus with Node Exporter or Zabbix or Nagios.

Comment: thanks so much.

let's say i have a python process running in my machine and i want to track how much ram, cpu it's consuming.
that's my need.
i need continuous monitoring for a certain process.

Comment: also, `top | grep "firefox"` is giving me the expected output.  but when i try to redirect it to a file it shows blank.
can you help me with that.

`top | grep "firefox" > /home/a/firefoxutilization.txt` is what i'm running.

Comment: You can redirect the top output itself into a file (press ctrl+c to stop the output) and then grep the output file after capturing the top data. [Capture output of top comamnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729720/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-top-command-in-a-file-in-linux) might come in handy. If you put your application into a docker container you could think about resource constraining / monitoring that way.