# Capture output of last executed command into a variable without affecting Vim and line returns

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim

From this question: [bash - automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable) I used this command:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='LAST="`cat /tmp/x`"; exec >/dev/tty; exec > >(tee /tmp/x)'
```

It works, but when I use Vim I get this:

```
# vim
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

Then Vim opens. But it takes a while. Is there a way to get rid of this message and the slowdown?

Also when I list dir and I echo $LAST it removes the return lines (\n). Is there a way to keep the return lines (\n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you ask for is hard do achieve. Vim tests if the output is a terminal. The command you've provided redirects the output to the `tee` command. `tee` saves its input (which also menans: command's output) to the file *and* outputs it to the terminal. But `vim` knows nothing about it. It only knows its output is not a terminal. So it outputs warning. And from the `vim`'s source code:

```
[...]
if (scriptin[0] == NULL)
    ui_delay(2000L, TRUE);
TIME_MSG("Warning delay");
```

which means this redirection will always get you 2 seconds delay.

Also, for example, `man vim` command will not work with such redirections, because terminal output has some attributest (e.g. width and height) which generic file hasn't. So... it won't work.